# Convert MODIS_Sinusoidal into WGS84 in Google Earth Engine

Tags: coordinate-system, google-earth-engine, modis, modis-reprojection-tool

I'm trying to transfer the Modis_Sinusoidal projection to the WGS84 projection in the Google Earth Engine. But I failed. I want to know how to solve it.

```
var bp = ee.FeatureCollection("users/miaohu828/bankment_polygon"),
    modisLandcover = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MCD12Q1");    
Map.setCenter(116.05380098858659, 30.63744097417238, 6);
var filtered2018 = modisLandcover.filter(
ee.Filter.date('2018-01-01', '2018-12-31'))
var landcover2018 = ee.Image(filtered2018.first())
var classified2018 = landcover2018.select('LC_Type1')
// The input image has a SR-ORG:6974 (sinusoidal) projection.
// Operations *before* the reproject call will be done in the projection
// specified by reproject().  The output results in another reprojection.
var reprojected = classified2018
    .unitScale(-2000, 10000)
    .reproject('EPSG:4326', null, 500);
    var visParams = {min: 1, max: 17};
```

Comment: What happened when you ran the code that you have presented?

Answer (score 4):

I didn't understand what you want to achieve, but if you change `min` and `max` value in `visParams` something appears on the map.

```
var bp = ee.FeatureCollection("users/miaohu828/bankment_polygon");
var modisLandcover = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MCD12Q1");    
var filtered2018 = modisLandcover.filter(ee.Filter.date('2018-01-01', '2018-12-31'))
var landcover2018 = ee.Image(filtered2018.first())
var classified2018 = landcover2018.select('LC_Type1')
var reprojected = classified2018
    .unitScale(-2000, 10000)
    .reproject('EPSG:4326', null, 500);
var visParams = {min: 0.1665, max: 0.1681};

Map.setCenter(116.0538, 30.6374, 6);
Map.addLayer(reprojected, visParams, "Reprojected")
Map.addLayer(bp, {}, "bankment_polygon");
```

[image]